# Different action depending on returned content type in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, content-type

Is there any way I can evaluate the returned content type of a jquery ajax request and do different things depending on the content type?

For example if the conten type is html I'd like to append this to a certain div on my page.
If the content type is text/javascript I'd like to just evaluate the javascript.
If the content type is JSON I'd like to process the returned JSON data according to my needs.

Not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
var xhr = $.post(action, params, function(data) {                           
     if (xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == 'application/pdf') {
    ...
     }                          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible...

```
$.ajax({

  // Set the URL, method, parameters, yada, yada, yada

  complete:function(xhr, stat) {
    var typ = xhr.contentType;
    var res = xhr.responseText;

    alert("Type: " + typ);
  }
});
```