# WebApi - returning image or movie media types to be rendered in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api

My current need is to have a method on my WebAPI controller, which returns the byte array stored in my database as either an image or a movie to my client, wherein it will be rendered in html accordingly.

One of the main issues is that the client side html has to support down to IE8, so HTML5 tags are out of question.

My controller method so far looks like:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(int _id)
    {
        try
        {
            var content = result from DB call

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content.File);

            if(content.ContentType.Format == Format.Image)
            {
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/x-ms-wmv");
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

The above code works nicely and returns the data I need.  When it comes to client side, I have tried to use the object HTML tag as this can display both movies and images.  So client side I have this:

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="path/to/api">
```

This kind of works, but it is not rendering the data correctly, I actually have to manually resize the screen when the data value changes.  I get a warning of 'Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png' which makes sense since I have not specified the type of object in the HTML since it can be 1 of 2 types.

There is also a need to loop the videos which I have not figured out either.

Large and fairly open question I know, but does anyone know if this is a decent approach, or can recommend an alternative.

Comment: Looks great, I think I would prefer to use jQuery and inspect the header to see if I have an img or video returned. Something like was described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228184/different-action-depending-on-returned-content-type-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: that is pretty much the current approach I am trying currently.  Getting the content type and then appending the type attribute to the object tag accordingly